# get_template_directory_uri() suddenly started returning the wrong value

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

Out of nowhere on my site, the function `get_template_directory_uri()` has started returning the completely wrong value when using my child theme. It was all working just a moment ago, with the child theme and everything. Then all of a sudden it started returning `http://example.com/~villageofmanteno/vmanteno-child`, when it should be `http://example.com/~villageofmanteno/yootheme-child`. Now the entire site is broken and all script URLs return a 404. The site root is at `/~villageofmanteno`.

This is the really weird part now, that last segment of the URL that I'm getting, `vmanteno-child` doesn't appear to come from anywhere. I never typed that in anywhere, no files or themes are named with `vmanteno`. The word `vmanteno` was never in my code. So I have no idea where that could have come from.

I even tried deleting my child theme, re-creating it, and copying over my old files and it's still broken. When I turn off the child theme everything is fine.

The child theme folder is called `yootheme-child`.

Right now the only template file I have in my child theme is `page-meetings.php`, but this issue is affecting the whole site on every page, so this can't have anything to do with it.

Here is my `style.css`:

```
/*
Theme Name: YOOtheme Child
Theme URI: https://yootheme.com
Template: yootheme
Author: YOOtheme
Author URI: https://yootheme.com
Description: A powerful, flexible and elegant website builder that allows you to create complex pages within minutes and customize every aspect of the theme.
Version: 1.21.6.1569423942
Updated: 2019-09-25 15:05:42
*/
```

And my `functions.php`:

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
        if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
            $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
        return $uri;
    }
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

Also I should mention, the WordPress Address and Site Address are both set to the correct value `http://example.com/~villageofmanteno`.

Edit: `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` are returning the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `get_template_directory_uri()` will returns the URL for the parent theme, if you want the URL from your child theme, then you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Note that also both functions have internal filters that allows change the URL, like `get_template_directory_uri()` have a filter called `template_directory_uri`, so it's possible for a 3rd party theme or plugin have been changing it.

Comment: Well, the URL it does return is not my parent theme folder either, it should be `yootheme` if that was the case. It doesn't correspond to anything at all. Also WordPress itself is not producing the correct URLs for its script and CSS imports, causing everything to 404. There are no other themes installed.

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` are returning the same thing actually. I also haven't changed any plugins, and there are very few.

Comment: But if WordPress itself is not proper generating correct URLs, so the problems sounds to be more than just the theme, there's some code change it on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on fixing this. Deleting the old child theme and creating a new one with the same name was causing the same issue, but creating a new child theme with a different name somehow worked. Changing the theme name back to yootheme-child breaks it again. No clue why.